# Sketchfab dragon doesn't appear correctly in blender

Tags: animation, rigging, gltf

I downloaded a rigged an animated dragon model created in sketchfab, I imported the model into blender, but it doesn't appear properly, wings appears to be twisted. I need help fixing the wings[image]

The wings are meant to look like this[image]

I attached the Blend file below

[image]

Comment: Please include the images directly in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I have included the images

Comment: Is there a possibility you’ve accidentally scaled the bones for the wings?

Comment: No, I didn't scale the bones of the wings

Comment: Hmm. Is this model free?

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: I attached the Blend file, kindly review.